# Problem following microsoft tutorial. (Stuck at step 3)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, security, authentication

I am following a tutorial to learn how to use form based security in ASP.NET but i got stuck at step 3, when i have to create the create the membership database. I am a newbie, could you give me a hand?

This is the tutorial i am following: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649314.aspx

And this is my problem:
[image]
Just in case the image is small, the error says:

> An error has occurred. Details of the
>   exception: A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a conne ction to SQL
>   Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that  the
>   instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes
>   Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
>   conne ction to SQL Server)

Could someone more experienced, help me solving this? I already posted a similar question today, but i cant fix it, i don't understand what i should do.

Ill appreciate a lot your help.

**UPDATE**

I tried to verified the connection as recommended in this link:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.ii.doc/opt/tlsmss08.htm

But something goes wrong:
[image]

**UPDATE 2**

I followed sehe's suggestion and i made the query for retrieving the date pass. So i assumed i was connected. The next thing i did was, try to grant database access as says in the tutorial, but i cant make the queries pass:

This are the queries just incase the image is small:

> -- Create a SQL Server login for the Network Service account sp_grantlogin
>   'NT AUTHORITY\Network Service'
>
> -- Grant the login access to the membership database USE aspnetdb GO
>   sp_grantdbaccess 'NT AUTHORITY\Network
>   Service', 'Network Service'
>
> -- Add user to database role USE aspnetdb GO sp_addrolemember
>   'aspnet_Membership_FullAccess',
>   'Network Service'

Only the first one seem to pass ok.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Well just asking the obvious: is there a SQL server instance running and have you verified you can connect to it using your windows user?

Comment: The SQL server is runnnig. How can i check if i can connect to it? I dont see that option in SQL server configuration Manager.

Comment: Use a command line tool like `isql` (or `osql`, don't remember) or use [`SQLServer Express`](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/express.aspx) (free)

Comment: Check my update see that i did to check. I think something is wrong. It says there are problems stablishing a connection.

Comment: You used a procedure to check remote database links from an IBM site... Did you connect successfully (that's the first dialog you have to pass in SS Express)? And does a simple query (e.g. `SELECT GETDATE() AS CurrentDateTime`) work?

Comment: Yes that passed! `SELECT GETDATE() AS CurrentDateTime` So that means i can connect. What should i do next?

Comment: I'm not so sure whether it is safe to assume you connected as I'm detecting a fair bit of confusion. Meanwhile Henk H. has found the time to formulate the steps that I'd like to check really, so I'd go to his list fist.

Comment: As you said i assumed i was connected, so i decided to move one to the next step of the tutorial, but it seems like i cant access ASPNETDB.MDF I dont know if this has something to do with that?(See update 2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key phrase would be:

> Unable to connect to SQL Server database.

So make sure

- you have installed an SQL (Express) database, and find out the instance name. Usually `SqlExpress`
- that it is configured for TCP Access
- that (local) is working as an alias

A few ideas to try

- run the script (the command window) as Admin
- replace `(local)` with `.\SqlExpress`
- run ASPNET_RegSQl without any parameters. IIRC it will start a GUI with a Wizard.

Comment: @sfrj: See e.g. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tolong/archive/2007/08/19/unable-to-connect-sql-server-2005.aspx because this is likely a FAQ

Comment: I did that, i enabled the network protocol. `TCP/IP:Enabled` also i have `Named Pipes:Enabled` I also went through the list above, i just didnt do the alias thing. Could you tell me what should i type on port, when i create new Alias?

Comment: I don't think you should create a new alias, just find out the existing.

Comment: How can i do that? I don't understand

Comment: Forget 'Alias', you need an Instance name. Start Sql Config manager, You'll see an entry like "Protocols for XXX" : XXX is the name you need. But how did my last suggestion work?

Comment: Your last suggestion about the TCP was already implemented. My SQLServer already had TCP as it says in the blog u posted. I am starting to think that i might have some compatibility issues. I use win Vista(x86) SQL Server2005(SP1), currently i am downloading SP2 to see if that fix something. Thank you for your help, ill keep trying.

Comment: @sfrj my last suggestion was about using the wizard.

Comment: I did that too and i get the same error when i pick try to pick database.